# Refering parent bean using ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

As a Spring beginner I get used to use `BeanFactory` :

```
     Resource res1 = new ClassPathResource("bus.xml");
     BeanFactory factory1 = new XmlBeanFactory(res1);


     Resource res2 = new ClassPathResource("travel.xml");
     BeanFactory factory2 = new XmlBeanFactory(res2,factory1);
```

Those configuration comes since I'm using 2 separate XML configs. which using `<ref parent="bus">` in `travel.xml`.

*bus.xml*

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
<bean id="bus" class="java4s.Bus">
<property name="maxSpeed" value="80" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

*Travel.xml*

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="travel" class="java4s.Travel">
        <property name="v"> 
            <ref parent="bus" />   
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Thinking about using `ApplicationContext` I have a question how to make those configs to be equally to `ApplicationContext`, since in the above example `factory1` instance need to be passed to `XmlBeanFactory (...,...)` as second argument of the constructor, I've tried to google it many times since this morning but can't find the exact example. I need to transform them to something like :

```
ApplicationContext con1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bus.xml");
ApplicationContext con2 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("travel.xml",con1);
```

Thanks.

Edit : I try `@JorgeCampos`'s suggestion :

```
ApplicationContext con1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bus.xml","travel.xml");

        Object o = con1.getBean("travel");
        Journey j = (Journey)o;
```

But throwing me an error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'travel' defined in class path resource
>   [travel.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'bus' while setting
>   bean property 'v'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'travel' defined in class path resource
>   [travel.xml]: Can't resolve reference to bean 'bus' in parent factory:
>   no parent factory available

**EDIT : I FOUND THE ANSWER:**

it's :

`new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"travel.xml"}, new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bus.xml"));`

which is written in docs as (is it ?)

`public ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String[] configLocations, ApplicationContext parent)`,

Thank you very much everyone! (specially *@M. Deinum*)

Comment: Have you tried: `("bus.xml", "travel.xml")` as the docs refers it as string array `(String... configLocations)`

Comment: @JorgeCampos, thank you, I try it (with 1 & 2 ApplicationContext) but still throws me an error.

Comment: So add the stacktrace of the error and we will see what is wrong. when you tryied `("bus.xml", "travel.xml")`

Comment: @JorgeCampos, Thank you please see my update above.

Comment: It seems that your xmls have references to each other or at least to elements of each other. You have to define the right order of the creation e.g. if in bus.xml you have an element that is defined on travel.xml it have to come first on the instantiation of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. You have to analyse your xmls to define the right dependencies. So, try the inverse `("travel.xml", "bus.xml")`

Comment: And have you actually tried your own code and have you taken the time to take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html#ClassPathXmlApplicationContext-java.lang.String:A-org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext-).

Comment: @Deinum , the `BeanFactory` way works just fine , but the `ApplicationContext` way is what I meant. But I read the docs also until right now.

Comment: @Deinum ,Eureka!!! I got it , it's `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"travel.xml"}, new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bus.xml"));` which is written in docs as `public ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String[] configLocations,
                                      ApplicationContext parent)`, thank you everyone..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to compose multiple xml configuration files using the [import element](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-xml-import).